# Unable to gracefully finish an Airflow DAG

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, airflow

I have a `spark-streaming` job that runs on EMR, scheduled by Airflow. We want to gracefully terminate this EMR cluster every week.

But when I issue the `kill` or `SIGTERM` signal to the running `spark-streaming` application it is reporting as "failed" task in the Airflow DAG. This is preventing the DAG to move further, preventing the next run from triggering.

Is there any way either to kill the running `spark-streaming` app to mark success or to let the DAG complete even though it sees the task as failed?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way either to kill the running spark-streaming app to mark success or to let the DAG complete even though it sees the task as failed?

For the first part, can you share your code that kills the Spark app?  I think you should be able to have this task return success and have everything downstream "just work".

I'm not too familiar with EMR, but looking at the docs it looks like "job flow" is their name for the Spark cluster.  In that case, are you using the built-in `EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator`?

I wonder if the failed task is the cluster terminating propagating back an error code or something?  Also, is it possible that the cluster is failing to terminate and your code is raising an exception leading to a failed task?

To answer the second part, if you have multiple upstream tasks, you can use an alternate trigger rule on the operator to determine which downstream tasks run.

```py
class TriggerRule(object):
    ALL_SUCCESS = 'all_success'
    ALL_FAILED = 'all_failed'
    ALL_DONE = 'all_done'
    ONE_SUCCESS = 'one_success'
    ONE_FAILED = 'one_failed'
    DUMMY = 'dummy'
```

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/trigger_rule.py

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/docs/concepts.rst#trigger-rules